# In a vim function, how do you set a register to a value that includes new lines?

Tags: vim

When I run the following as a :command in vim, the register is set properly.

```
let @a='line1^@line2'
```

When I press <kbd>"</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>p</kbd>, I get

```
line1
line2
```

When I put the line in a function in my .vimrc,

```
function! SetA()
    let @a='line1^@line2'
endfunction
```

call it,

```
:call SetA()
```

vim generates the following error.

```
E115: Missing quote: 'line1
E15: Invalid expression: 'line1
```

It seems like `^@` (that I entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>@</kbd>) is getting interpreted as an extra line when it's part of a function.  How do I escape this, or prevent it from happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this would do:

```
function! SetA()
    let @a="line1\nline2"
endfunction
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Kent's answer that you found working for you, instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>@</kbd> that you tried, try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd>.

Hope that helps.